# Passing a function pointer and a data pointer argument to a function that takes function pointer with pointer to data argument in C

Tags: c, function-pointers

from main I'm trying to pass a function with an address to a struct to another function I'm able to edit that takes a function pointer with a aoid pointer as an argument
the function I'm trying to pass to attachReleased in main is tareFunc():

```
attachReleased(&Btn0Params,  tareFunc(&hx711));
```

and here's the code in another C file:

```
void attachReleased(btn_params_t *BtnParams, void (*BtnISR)(void *args)){
  // printf("Attached pin #%d\n ", BtnParams->BtnPin);
  BtnParams->ReleasedISR = BtnISR(&args);
  gpio_isr_handler_add(BtnParams->BtnPin, buttonISR, (btn_params_t *)BtnParams);
}
```

Is it possible to do what I'm trying to achieve with passing the function pointer and the argument pointer at the same time or do you have to separate them which is a little inconvenient?

Answer (score 2):

You're not actually passing a function pointer and its arguments here:

```
attachReleased(&Btn0Params,  tareFunc(&hx711));
```

What you're actually doing is calling `tareFunc` and passing its return value to `attachReleased`

You need to pass the parameter to `tareFunc` as a separate argument to `attachReleased`.

```
void attachReleased(btn_params_t *BtnParams, void (*BtnISR)(void *), void *args){
  // printf("Attached pin #%d\n ", BtnParams->BtnPin);
  //BtnParams->ReleasedISR = BtnISR(args);
  BtnISR(args);
  gpio_isr_handler_add(BtnParams->BtnPin, buttonISR, (btn_params_t *)BtnParams);
}
```

Which can then be called like this:

```
attachReleased(&Btn0Params,  tareFunc, &hx711);
```

Note also that since the function pointer `BtnISR` has a `void` return type, that there's no value to return and use.

Comment: Well I actually tried was passing the pointer to ISR function tareFunc() along with it's parameters pointer &hx711 to attachReleased() as I need to feel a values in another struct like void (*ReleasedISR)(void *args); which I try to store both the pointer of function and pointer of args under single definition but now from my understanding it's not an option in C and I must separate tareFunc and hx711 pointer to pass it further the function correct me if I'm wrong?

Comment: @Pongo Yes, if you want to call `tareFunc` from inside `attachReleased` via a function pointer, you need to pass the function pointer and the arguments to that function separately to `attachReleased`.

Comment: Ok It's just that I'm in the stages of idealizing my C writing skills for drivers and libraries so I'm looking to write code in the absolute cleanest most efficient and understandable way and passing 2 things to mean 1 thing seem a bit off, but I'll take that fact for now until noticed otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

As coded you are passing the value returned by tareFunc to attachReleased so unless tareFunc returns  void (*BtnISR)(void *args).  It isn't possible to pass the value and the function ptr in this way.  You could pass the arguments to the func ptr as an additional argument.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, what you want is something like this in your first file:

```
attachReleased(&Btn0Params, &tareFunc, &hx711);
```

and like this in your other C file:

```
void attachReleased(btn_params_t *BtnParams, void (*BtnISR)(void *), void *args)){
  // printf("Attached pin #%d\n ", BtnParams->BtnPin);
  BtnParams->ReleasedISR = (*BtnISR)(args);
  gpio_isr_handler_add(BtnParams->BtnPin, buttonISR, (btn_params_t *)BtnParams);
}
```